# I am looking for a short live action Sci Fi film where a man is given a box that shows what will happen to him 5 minutes in the future

Tags: story-identification, movie

I think the short film was on Vimeo about five years ago (and yes I have tried looking there.) It showed a younger man being given a box by an older man and when he looked inside it showed a diorama of himself and his surroundings but slightly further forward in time (I think about 5 minutes) so he could see in advance what was going to happen to him.

A great deal of the the film took place on a train station concourse and involved a romantic relationship with his girlfriend and I think watching it end. It reminded me very strongly of Philip K Dick *The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch* and Don Hertzfeldt films, but it's neither of those, I've checked.

I didn't note the title.  I have tried Google, Dust and YouTube searches but can't find it.

Comment: I don't think this is the one you are seeking. But the plot sounds similar to the Twilight Zone episode "A Most Unusual Camera."  I checked some of the other referenced similar stories/movies and didn't see anything like what you mentioned. But I may have missed something if you want to take a look:   https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734543/

Comment: What was that box looking like?

Comment: Thank you very much I could pick myself for not getting the title but these look really interesting to.

Comment: Do you remember how long the film was?

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] that information into your question?